# PHP help on number Generater

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <title>Game Process</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php
    $userguess= $_POST["number"];
    $gennumber = rand(0,20);
    if ($gennumber > $userguess) {
        $result="lost";
        echo "You have lost your guess was too low! The number was:".$gennumber;
    } elseif ($gennumber == $userguess){
        echo "Wow you are extreamly lucky to get ".$gennumber;  $result="won";
    } else {
        echo "You have lost your guess was too high! The number was: ".$gennumber;
    $result="lost";
    }
    ?>
```

this is the problem I am trying to see if `$count` is equal to nothing and if it is than set it to 1. I have done some research into `isset` and `empty` put I don't know how to use them and as I said Iam a newbie in programming!

```
    <?php
    $_SESSION['count']=$count;
    if (!$count){

         } else {
             $count = 1;
         }


    if ($result == "lost"){
    echo '<a href="Game.php"><input type="button" value="Have another guess!"/></a>';
    $count +1;
    echo "<br>your number of guess are: ".$count; 
    } else {
        echo "well done!<br>";
        echo "your number of guess are: ".$count; 
    }

    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: change `$count +1;` to `++$_SESSION['count'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SESSION['count']) && !empty($_SESSION['count']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['count'])) {
    $count = (int)$_SESSION['count'];
} else {
    $count = 0;
    $_SESSION['count'] = (int)$count;
}

if ($result == "lost"){
    echo '<a href="Game.php"><input type="button" value="Have another guess!"/></a>';
    $count++; //increase $count var
    $_SESSION['count'] = (int)$count;
    echo "<br>your number of guess are: ".$count; 
} else {
    echo "well done!<br>";
    echo "your number of guess are: ".$count; 
}
```

Check if this handles it for you :) I'm checking if the value being received in session is set, not empty and if it is numeric. If so, I'm gonna save it into the variable $count and cast it to an integer (just to be sure).

If not, make it 0.

Comment: sorry im comfused what shall i write in my code?

Comment: You can replace where your PHP starts in second tag with my code. Let me know if it works.

Comment: there is some other error? have a look at http://www.poptani.com/asim/computerscience/Game.php

Comment: I don't see any error. What is it?

Comment: the number of gueses is staying to one. each time somone guesses a number on it i want it to the number of guesses to increase by one.

Comment: You're not changing it in the $_SESSION. I've updated the code. Try it.

Comment: Thanks so much i would be stuck without you!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

You have this code:

```
$_SESSION['count']=$count;
if (!$count){

 } else {
     $count = 1;
 }
```

You're assigning `$count` to a value in the `$_SESSION` array. You're not changing the value of `$count` there. If you wish to check if `$count` is equal to `0`, why can't you use:

```
if($count == 0)
{
    $count = 1;
}
```

And finally, `$count + 1` should be `++ $count`.